# Active Record, validates_uniqueness_off with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating a Course application in Ruby on Rails. This Course application has chapters with each chapter having a quiz.

For the quiz, I want to apply the validation that a question can have only one answer where the is_correct attribute is set to true.

On my Answer model I tried to define this validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :is_correct, conditions: { where(is_correct: true) }
```

But I'm getting a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing this (->) mark as it it told in Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of). Try like this :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :is_correct, conditions: -> { where(is_correct: true) }
```

Thanks